# Connecting to wifi with ConnectivityManager not possible

Tags: android, wifi

I'm trying to connect to a wifi with code. Here is my simplified code:

```kotlin
val wifiNetworkSpecifier = WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
    .setSsid(ssid)
    .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
    .build()

val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder().apply {
    addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
    if (useCapabilities) {
        addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
        addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_RESTRICTED)
    }
    setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier)
}.build()

connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback)
```

<sup>[The full code can be found here](https://github.com/rekire/WifiBug/blob/fb87bec2cbeaf83cf98a9f70fcd476b4c827b45a/app/src/main/java/eu/rekisoft/android/wifibug/MainActivity.kt#L103)</sup>
When `useCapabilities` is true I get no visual feedback, the callbacks are not helpful too. When I set the capabilities `onUnavailable()` is called, but I see no reason why. I can connect with the same network which I try it by hand.

I have a full sample app here: https://github.com/rekire/WifiBug

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I'm using a Pixel 6 with Android 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WifiNetworkSpecifier is not meant to work with capability `NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET` so it will always call `onUnavailable`. I explain in my self-answered question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73178258/467509

I personally think Google should tell you this in Android Studio in a linter or something, and not just call `onUnavailable` and bury a debug message in LogCat.

Comment: Ah I totally forgot this question. Yep wrong API